# Migrating from Backbone JS to AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a backbone application. However AngularJS looks great, a lot less code needed and it seems much easier to manage so I would like to try porting it accross.

One thing I am not clear on.

I have many models for storing data in Backbone. For example `@model.set(foo: "bar")` which I find really useful for my application I can compare models etc... over write.

What is the best way to store data in  Angular? Does a scope behave like a model?

Answer (score 0):

Angular is model agnostic, you can use Plain Old JavaScript Objects. Or create .get .set functions with the functionality you want!

A scope does not behave like a model, a scope is where the model lives (instantiated/altered/read from etc.).

Comment: okay, that's neat. How could I build a function to that? I am guessing it could be whateveriwant.set(:foo "bar")

Comment: well in in JavaScript you can just say whateveryouwant.foo = bar, I don't have much experience with backbone so I might be missing some of the functionality of its .set method. But I am assuming it is used for things like observing and data-binding. Angular does that for you by you having defined in a controller $scope.model.foo = bar

Comment: The data-binding part is automatic. If you update the model ($scope variable) anywhere, it's reflected everywhere that model is called. No setters/getters required. It's stored in memory already. If you're talking about storing back to the server, that's another topic (but still pretty simple.)

Comment: Also, if you want to manage models at a more complex level and/or share them among multiple $scopes, then you can use a service. Services are normally where you'd interact with the server, but they can also be used as their own "shared scope" among different parts of the app.